# Code Layout regarding GUI Development

Tags: java, layout, user-interface, javafx

I'm currently learning to create Graphical Interfaces using JavaFX as i feel like it's
more powerful than Swing and easier to code by hand instead of having to resort to
GUIBuilder.
While this also includes Swing i have read quite a few tutorials so far and I always see
all the code being written in either the main() or start() methods.

For example this code example from java.about.com:

```
//Imports are listed in full to show what's being used
//could just import javafx.*
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ApplicationWindow extends Application {

    //JavaFX applicatoin still use the main method.
    //It should only ever contain the call to the launch method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    //starting point for the application
    //this is where we put the code for the user interface
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        //The primaryStage is the top-level container
        primaryStage.setTitle("example Gui");

        //The BorderPane has the same areas laid out as the
        //BorderLayout layout manager
        BorderPane componentLayout = new BorderPane();
        componentLayout.setPadding(new Insets(20,0,20,20));

        //The FlowPane is a conatiner that uses a flow layout
        final FlowPane choicePane = new FlowPane();
        choicePane.setHgap(100);
        Label choiceLbl = new Label("Fruits");

        //The choicebox is populated from an observableArrayList
        ChoiceBox fruits = new ChoiceBox(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Asparagus", "Beans", "Broccoli", "Cabbage"
         , "Carrot", "Celery", "Cucumber", "Leek", "Mushroom"
         , "Pepper", "Radish", "Shallot", "Spinach", "Swede"
         , "Turnip"));

        //Add the label and choicebox to the flowpane
        choicePane.getChildren().add(choiceLbl);
        choicePane.getChildren().add(fruits);

        //put the flowpane in the top area of the BorderPane
        componentLayout.setTop(choicePane);

        final FlowPane listPane = new FlowPane();
        listPane.setHgap(100);
        Label listLbl = new Label("Vegetables");

        ListView vegetables = new ListView(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Apple", "Apricot", "Banana"
         ,"Cherry", "Date", "Kiwi", "Orange", "Pear", "Strawberry"));
        listPane.getChildren().add(listLbl);
        listPane.getChildren().add(vegetables);
        listPane.setVisible(false);

        componentLayout.setCenter(listPane);

        //The button uses an inner class to handle the button click event
        Button vegFruitBut = new Button("Fruit or Veg");
        vegFruitBut.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                //switch the visibility for each FlowPane
                choicePane.setVisible(!choicePane.isVisible());
                listPane.setVisible(!listPane.isVisible());
            }
        });

        componentLayout.setBottom(vegFruitBut);

        //Add the BorderPane to the Scene
        Scene appScene = new Scene(componentLayout,500,500);

        //Add the Scene to the Stage
        primaryStage.setScene(appScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

But coding everything in the main() or start() goes against principles i learnt at school
and also seems like a bad thing to do too me.
As i always used to code splitting everything up in different methods and than keeping a clean main() by only calling methods to do stuff, so it's easy to read up on the programs execution path. As i see all tutorials etc. going against this by putting al their GUI code in the main or start methods i started wondering if this is conventional to do regarding GUI code or should i still try to put everything under custom methods and keep a clean main()?

Also could anyone share neat tutorials regarding JavaFX? I can't seem to find much in this matter.

EDIT: I should really just ask for a good example on how a class hierarchy of an advanced application interface looks like to get some ideas.

Hope this was a clear question,
thanks in advance.

Jasper.

Comment: Also being really new to JavaFX, it seems like a pain to put all EventHandles in the main() and not as we'd do it in regular Java by creating actual methods for these functionalities.

Comment: I would do something like FruitChoiceBox fcb = new (a class that extends ChoiceBox); and then have that class do all the adding fruits and event handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a GUI class that holds all of your GUI code together, or simply create a GUI method that resides below main. Then, in main, you could call:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  launch(args);
}

public void start()
{
  launchGUI(Stage primaryStage)
}
```

And then create your `launchGUI` method either in the same class, or create a new class specifically for the GUI and them use `import` to import it into the class containing `main`/`start`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i did indeed pull this off. But i think i should mention it really is just unclear of how a class hierarchy for an application interface should look like. And would love to see some examples on this :).

Comment: Class heirarchy fully depends on the coder, as everyone has their own tastes. Typically, coders will place all of their views (GUIs) separate from their models (objects), and then place their controllers (methods, etc), separate as well (known as an MVC).  As the question you are asking is opinion-based, it is difficult to provide a concrete answer.